# rearrange 3d numpy array with list of indices

Tags: python, numpy, indexing

I have a 3 dimensional numpy array of dimensions 333*333*52

I have a 333 element lists of indices ranging from 0-332 eg [4 12 332 0 ...] that I wish to use to rearrange the first two dimensions of the 3d array

In matlab I would do:

```
rearranged_array = original_array(new_order, new_order, :)
```

But this approach does not work with numpy:

```
rearranged_array = original_array[new_order, new_order, :]
```

Produces a 333*52 array

While:

```
rearranged_array = original_array[new_order][new_order, :]
```

Does not get things in the right order

Edit:

This seems to work:

```
rearranged_array = original_array[new_order, :][:, new_order]
```

This seems a lot less intuitive to me than the matlab method - are there any better ways?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your third one

```
rearranged_array = original_array[new_order][new_order, :]
```

is just doing the same operation twice.

You want

```
rearranged_array = original_array[new_order][:, new_order]
```

The reason your first solution doesn't work is because numpy only does the rearrangement if the index passed is a list or array, but if you pass `new_order, new_order`, that is a tuple.

Another solution is to do

```
 rearranged_array = original_array[np.row_stack((new_order, new_order))]
```

---

nb. you keep doing things like `a[x, y, :]` and `a[x, :]`. Trailing `:` are superfluous. `a[x, y]` and `a[x]` respectively do exactly the same thing.

Comment: I wouldn't say trailing `:` are superfluous.  The code doesn't need them because they will be inferred.  But humans often need them to keep dimensions straight.